# Subquery table based on sys.tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve all primary keys iin a fact table and then count the number of records in that fact table grouped by that id, however so far i can only seem to get all the primary keys and its talbe. i guess i need to make some kind of subquery

```
SELECT
tab1.name AS [FactTable],
col1.name AS [PrimaryKey]
FROM sys.indexes ind1
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = ind1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch1
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch1.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.object_id = tab1.object_id AND col1.name like '%Id'     
WHERE tab1.name like 'Fact%' AND ind1.is_primary_key = 1
```

sample output

```
primaryKey    countRecordsGroupedByPrimaryKey
2             4000
3             8343
4             203
1             4023
```

Comment: If you want to count the records in the table (ie access the _data_, contrasting with merely reading table _structure_), you'll have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: do you have any examples for it in this case or good links, i'm not to familiar with sql server syntax

Comment: [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29cf9cb1-525a-4e50-8db5-ed7a416fd142/dynamic-sql-to-list-all-tables-in-a-database-with-row-count-for-each-table?forum=transactsql) could help

Comment: If you're truly referring to the PK of the fact table, counting the fact table records grouped by the PK will return every row, counted once.  PK has to be unique in a table.  Can you post a sample output of what you're expecting to see?  Are you trying to determine how many dimensions are referenced by each fact table?

Comment: i've updated with output example

Comment: Are you wanting to count the records by the Primary Key of a Dimension table referenced as a foreign key from the Fact table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I going out on a limb and guessing that you want to count the number of each dimensionPK used in your fact table.  If a fact table has references to two different dimensions, you need two different statements to count the usage by that dimension.

For the query below, provide your fact table name and schema and it should generate a count statement joining your fact and dim and grouping by the join keys.
- If a fact table has two different FK relationships, you'll get two different statements.
- If a table uses a composite PK, both key columns will be included in the join

This is complicated and I don't have any tables with multiple FKs to test it on, so please let me know if it does what you want.

```
DECLARE @NameOfTableWithFKs sysname = 'your fact table name',
        @SchemaOfTableWithFKs sysname = 'dbo';

WITH JoinColumns
AS (SELECT  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent.object_id)) AS ParentTableName,
            QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced.object_id)) AS ReferencedTableName,
            QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(parent.name) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced.object_id)) + '.'
            + QUOTENAME(referenced.name) AS JoinColumn,
            QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(referenced.name) AS GroupingColumn
    FROM    sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
      INNER JOIN sys.columns AS parent
        ON parent.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
           AND  parent.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
      INNER JOIN sys.columns AS referenced
        ON referenced.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
           AND  referenced.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
    WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(parent.object_id) = @NameOfTableWithFKs
            AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent.object_id) = @SchemaOfTableWithFKs
   ),
     JoinTables
AS (SELECT  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(tbl.object_id)) AS ParentTableName,
            QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(rtbl.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(rtbl.object_id)) AS ReferencedTableName
    FROM    sys.tables AS tbl
      INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS cstr
        ON cstr.parent_object_id = tbl.object_id
      INNER JOIN sys.tables AS rtbl
        ON rtbl.object_id = cstr.referenced_object_id
    WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(tbl.object_id) = @NameOfTableWithFKs
            AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.object_id) = @SchemaOfTableWithFKs
   )
SELECT  'SELECT Count(*)' + ( SELECT    ', ' + JC.GroupingColumn
                              FROM  JoinColumns AS JC
                              WHERE JC.ParentTableName = jt.ParentTableName
                                    AND JC.ReferencedTableName = jt.ReferencedTableName
                              FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) + ' FROM ' + JT.ParentTableName + ' INNER JOIN ' + JT.ReferencedTableName + ' ON'
        + SUBSTRING(( SELECT    ' AND ' + JC.JoinColumn
                      FROM  JoinColumns AS JC
                      WHERE   JC.ParentTableName = JT.ParentTableName
                              AND JC.ReferencedTableName = JT.ReferencedTableName
                      FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 5, 8000
                   ) + ' GROUP BY ' + SUBSTRING(( SELECT    ', ' + JC.GroupingColumn
                                                  FROM      JoinColumns AS JC
                                                  WHERE  JC.ParentTableName = JT.ParentTableName
                                                         AND JC.ReferencedTableName = JT.ReferencedTableName
                                                  FOR XML PATH('')
                                                ), 2, 8000
                                               )
FROM    JoinTables AS JT;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you are wanting to count all the rows in some tables based on some criteria. Not really sure why you care about the primary key portion since by definition a primary key must be unique so this could still be simplified to not check for primary key but whatever.

I did remove the join to sys.columns because why does it matter the name of the column unless you want only those table named Fact% and has a column named %Id.

This should get you pretty close as I understand it.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select TableName = ''' + tab1.name + ''', NumRows = count(*)  from ' + QUOTENAME(sch1.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(tab1.name) + ' UNION ALL '
FROM sys.indexes ind1
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = ind1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch1
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch1.schema_id
--INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
--    ON col1.object_id = tab1.object_id AND col1.name like '%Id'     
WHERE tab1.name like 'Fact%' 
    AND ind1.is_primary_key = 1


select @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10) + ' ORDER BY TableName'
select @SQL --uncomment the exec line below once you are comfortable that the dynamic sql is what you want.

--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```